# Need help passing two php variables through a url to the next page

Tags: php

I'm new to Php but what I need this php code to do is to pass two variables through the URL like this

```
<td align="center"><a class="btn btn-danger" href="reserve.php?distroid=<?php echo $row["distroid"] echo $row['orderid']; ?>">Place Order</a></td>
```

When we try and do it with just `distroid`, it works completely fine. But I'm unsure how to pass both values.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: SOLVED IT THANK YOU FOR THE HELP ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add more key for the query string like this :

```
<td align="center">
    <a class="btn btn-danger" 
        href="reserve.php?distroid=<?php echo $row["distroid"]; ?>&orderid=<?php echo $row['orderid']; ?>">
        Place Order
    </a>
</td>
```

Then you can get both `distroid` and `orderid`

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then accept this answer so the others know what answer that help you

Comment: I mean, click the check icon on the left of my answer

Comment: No problem, glad you understand

Answer (score 2):

**Try this query string like this :**

```
<td align="center">
    <a class="btn btn-danger" 
        href="reserve.php?distroid=<?php echo $row["distroid"]."&orderid=".$row['orderid']; ?>">
        Place Order
    </a>
</td>
```

Then you can get both variable **distroid** and **orderid**

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this anchor tag, it will work for you:

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="reserve.php?distroid=<?php echo $row['distroid']; 
 ?>&orderid=<?php echo $row['orderid']; ?>">
    Place Order
  </a>
```